# Simulate a simple "warning" in PHP

Tags: php

How can I simulate or force a warning in PHP? Is there a simple and common way to do this? Thank you!

I need it for an example script, because a webserver doesn't send any output, if there is a warning at any script. `error_handling(E_ALL)` displays the *warning with regular output*, but `error_handling(0)` hides not only the warning, it also hides the regular output ...?

Comment: Hiding the regular output is suspect. Please post the code where you experience that. As far as simulating a warning, trigger one with `trigger_error('this is a warning', E_USER_WARNING)`

Comment: Yes, it's very strange. I never see that before. So I just needed a quick example to send this to the webserver owner to show the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

trigger_error() is a way but it only works with E_USER_* error codes. If you want to simulate a real warning, you can use this:

```
preg_match('There will be a warning about missing delimiter here!', 'test');
```

You can also simulate an error with this:

```
$instance = NULL;
$instance->dummy();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$test=2;
if ($test>1)
{
trigger_error("A custom error has been triggered");
}
?>
```